# SQL Server HASHBYTES different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I want to get the SHA1 Hash of MATKHAU in SQL Server 2019 so I use HASHBYTES. But as you see the value of SELECT HASHBYTES is different from the value when I use Store Procedure. What's wrong with it? (It's the same input in MATKHAU)

Answer (score 1):

Data types matter:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', '123');   -- here VARCHAR
vs
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', N'123');  -- here NVARCHAR
```

The stored procedure takes parameter as `NVARCHAR` which causes implicit conversion when providing parameter to EXEC.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc8862897cf0fecc2a7ce808332664c2)**

Comment: Thanks. Finally can fix it

Comment: @QuyênNguyễn Glad to hear that. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)