# Is there any way to use dbo.HashPasswordString() of SQL Server with PHP similar to md5()?

Tags: php, sql-server, hash

I'm trying to create a registration and login form. Using SQL Server, I can do that like:

```
SELECT Account, Password
FROM USER
WHERE Account = ? and Password = dbo.HashPasswordString(?)
```

However, what I'm trying to do is a PHP function to handle the hashing without using `dbo.HashPasswordString()` in the query. It seems `HashPasswordString()` of SQL Server is not a MD5, so I can't do it just like `md5()` function in PHP. Is there any PHP function similar to that in SQL Server, so I can just hash it in PHP before inserting it in the query for example.

Comment: There is no such function in tsql. There are [chinese references](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) to a user-defined CLR function of that name. You should ask whoever is responsible for this database about the function and how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which you can specify as using MD5 e.g., `HASHBYTES ('md5', 'ABCDE')`.

Note you need to be *very* careful about the datatype in SQL Server - a HASHBYTES of a VARCHAR and one of an NVARCHAR will provide different results e.g., [SQL Server HASHBYTES different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958583/sql-server-hashbytes-different-values/63958740#63958740)

Comment: Well, the problem is that my application already uses passwords in a format such as: `U7796T13422FA0` which is clearly not a MD5 hash. It uses the standard dbo.HashPasswordString(). Is there any way to still accomplish what you're saying in php?

Comment: I don't believe that is a standard function in SQL Server (try googling it). It's probably a user defined function or similar? It's worth checking the algorithm because then you'd need to mirror that in the PHP.

Comment: If I create a new account with the following directly from the SQL Server management tool: `INSERT INTO table (Account,Password) VALUES('TestAccount',dbo.HashPasswordString('MyPassword')` then my application recognizes the account. It works. I just installed the MSSQL Server 2017 and didn't do any changes to it. So, that's what I'm trying to accomplish in PHP but not sure what kind of hash format is that. I assume it's a standard of SQL Server.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't on mine. However, the functions are stored within the database, and presumably you restored a previous database to get the current one? To confirm, you could try creating a new empty database (doesn't have to have anything in it) and, from within it, run `SELECT dbo.HashPasswordString('MyPassword')`

Comment: You're right. It's in Functions and it's there because I restored the database. So, after I found the function (it's not a big one:)) I'll have to see how it works and do something similar in php I guess. Also, is it safe to use parametrized statements with such functions included in the query? I guess it's not a problem, but just asking in terms of sql injection & security.

Comment: You also may want to review the system (e.g., is it up to standard with salts, good hashing algorithms, etc). But it's hard work to change over as you cannot just convert old passwords to new passwords (they're hashed) so you need to be able to run both concurrently.